# Start VS2012 Package Manager Console from Powershell Command Prompt

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, nuget-package

Is there a way to start the package manager console from either the powershell command prompt or the windows command window?

I have some commands I need to run as administrator, and would rather just run a powershell window as admin instead of shutting down and restarting VS2012 as admin.

Comment: As the NuGet prompt provides integration into VS's solution/project system I suspect the answer is no. That it uses a different profile file, so is a custom host, supports this. Might be worth starting with any modules the NuGet prompt loads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Richard is right.  One look at NuGet.Console.dll in dotPeek and it is pretty clear it has a lot of required hooks into the Visual Studio object model.  Plus, the actual console itself is a WPF UserControl and not a console subsystem app.