# when i run EF Code Migration from console - input string was not in a correct format error

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I faced with really strange problem.
I have console app with migration in child project. I use .Net 4 and EF 5.
Here is my migration:

```
            Sql(
            "INSERT [Script] ([Id], [CompanyId], [ScriptType], [ScriptCode], [Enable], [Schema]) VALUES (38500, 0, 3, N'if(Row.OccupancyCode == \"8500\") Row.MSBOccupancyId = 8500;', 1, N'SQA'), " +
            "(38510, 0, 3, N'if(Row.OccupancyCode == \"8510\") Row.MSBOccupancyId = 8510;', 1, N'SQA'), " +
            "(38535, 0, 3, N'if(Row.OccupancyCode == \"8535\") Row.MSBOccupancyId = 8535;', 1, N'SQA'); ");
```

When i run it from cmd like this:

> migrate.exe MSB.PI.Data.PortfolioInsight.dll /connectionString="Data
>   Source=SERVER;User=USER;Password=PASSWORD;Initial Catalog=AAA;"
>   /connectionProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" /verbose

I receive:

> VERBOSE: Target database is: 'AAA' (DataSource: evbyminsd1144,
>   Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Explicit). Applying
>   code-based migrations: [201304161824179_InsertBaseDataScripts].
>   Applying code-based migration: 201304161824179_InsertBaseDataScripts.
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingException: Input string
>   was not in a correct format.    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String
>   targetMigration, Boolean force)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Console.Program.Run()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Console.Program.Main(String[] args)
>   ERROR: Input string was not in a correct format.

But all statements is correct.

What is wrong, please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am running into the same issue while trying to integrate a build process into TeamCity. Just like @James-Morcom said, this is only an issue when running from migrate.exe. Everything seems to be fine under package manager console.

Answer (score 1):

**Hack warning**

Turns out I have to add a hack to resolve this issue.

The problem is most likely because migrate.exe is trying to do String.Format() somewhere.

The hack:

1. Create a DbMigration class and "new" the `Sql()` function so we can Escape the raw sql before passing it in `System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigration.Sql()`
2. Escape '{' and '}' using unicode

Code:

```
// This is a hack for:
//      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044838/when-i-run-ef-code-migration-from-console-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-fo
// Without it migrate.exe will not work if you try to run Sql("Select '{'")
// 
// This is most likely because migrate.exe is trying to do String.Format() somewhere
public abstract class DbMigration : System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigration
{
    protected internal new void Sql(string sql, bool suppressTransaction = false, object anonymousArguments = null)
    {
        base.Sql(Escape(sql), suppressTransaction, anonymousArguments);
    }

    // EF migrate.exe does not support any script with the character '{' or '}'
    // Encode them into unicode and add the strings on Sql server side
    private string Escape(string s)
    {
        return s.Replace("{", "'+NChar(123)+'").Replace("}", "'+NChar(125)+'");
    }
}
```

Things that I have tried but didn't work:

1. Run update-database in PowerShell by importing EntityFramework.psm1. You will get a message saying `The name of the current PowerShell host is 'ConsoleHost'`. This is because `update-database` uses a bunch of methods from NuGet's package manager console. [Read more here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2010/01/23/powershellhostversion-wtf.aspx)
2. Run package manager console from powershell. This is most likely not possible as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125395/start-vs2012-package-manager-console-from-powershell-command-prompt)
3. Trying to figure out why the problem doesn't exist in EntityFramework.psm1 and use their solution. The script contains 500 lines of code and is actually doing a lot more than just firing migrate.exe. Hacking it seems easier

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue parsing strings within raw SQL in a migration. The following valid SQL inside a migration also throws "Input string was not in a correct format" when run under migrate.exe:

```
Sql("SELECT '{'");
```

It **does** work from Package Manager Console though, so does seem to be an issue with migrate.exe specifically.

N.b. I was using 4.3.1.

One option may be to run the migration from Package Manager Console within Visual Studio with the "-Script" parameter:

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:"MigrationBeforeProblemOne" -TargetMigration:"ProblemMigration"
```

This would allow you to generate an SQL script to run rather than using migrate.exe, just to get this migration into the database (from which point migrate.exe would be able to skip this particular migration in future).